# How to add/remove elements from a MongoDB list using spring data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am using spring data to talk to mongo (although I know there are few downsides to it over the mongo driver for advanced use cases). My application has a mongodb document with one of the elements being a list. Now I want to add/delete specific elements from the list in the document.
Can someone please tell me if and how spring data supports that (considering its a basic operation)?

I did quite some web search but didn't seem to land on anything concrete.

Any help would be appreciable.

**UPDATE 1**:
Sample document:

```
{ id: 123, arr: [ 1,2,3,4]}
```

and after update

`{ id: 123, arr: [ 1,2,3]}` or `{ id: 123, arr: [ 1,2,3,4,5]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at the unit tests and it looks like you can use the mongo $pull and $push methods using the **Update** class.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/UpdateTests.java

You can see a tutorial here:

http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/01/spring-data-mongodb-update-document.html#.VVexP3UVhBc

So you'd be doing something like:

```
Update().pull("arr", 4);
Update().push("arr", 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a service which would handle this operation.

Assuming you are using one of Springs Repository interfaces your service could pull out the objects you need to update from the DB and then you would simply call .save() on each object.

```
Object o = repository.findById(someId);
o.setList(new ArrayList());
repository.save(o);
```

Another option would be to use the mongoOperation exposed by Spring data:

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-update-document/

This could be helpful if you are trying to update multiple documents.

Comment: Wooha! Be careful with this. This is not thread safe. If you are using more then one thread that can call this code you can get into race condition issues. I'll suggest not to use it anyway.